# How to control the buffer of Scanf.Scanning?

Tags: ocaml

The `Scanf` module appears to behave somewhat
counterintuitively in that it doesn’t respect the state of the
underlying channel:

```
(* prepare test data *)
let () =
  let oc = open_out "test.txt" in
  output_string oc "abcdefghij\n";
  close_out oc
;;

let ic = open_in "test.txt"

(* ic at offset 0: “ab…” *)
let () =
  let sc = Scanf.Scanning.from_channel ic in
  let s = Scanf.bscanf sc "%2s" (fun s -> s) in
  Printf.eprintf "read [%s]\n" s (* -> [ab] *)
;; (* sc out of scope at this point *)

(* hint: close ic here and reopen for expected result *)
seek_in ic 4

(* ic at offset 4: “ef…” *)
let () =
  let sc = Scanf.Scanning.from_channel ic in
  let s = Scanf.bscanf sc "%2s" (fun s -> s) in
  Printf.eprintf "read [%s]\n" s (* -> [cd] ‽ *)
;;

close_in ic
```

Apparently the internal buffer of `Scanning.t` survives it
unless the channel is recreated. Is there another way to force a
resync? The [docs](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Scanf.Scanning.html#TYPEin_channel)
claim that “Reading starts at current reading position of ic.”

I’d appreciate a pointer to where exactly this behavior is
documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just on general design principles, I would say that a call to `Scanf.Scanning.from_channel` moves responsibility for the channel to the `Scanf` module. Things aren't guaranteed to work if you go behind the back of the `Scanf` module and manipulate the channel directly (as you do here with `seek_in`).

Things work similarly with virtually every layered I/O library that I've used. E.g., you can't use `fdopen()` from Unix stdio and expect to read data through the `FILE` abstraction while also manipulating the underlying file descriptor in arbitrary ways.

It might be good if the documentation mentioned these issues (in both cases).

Comment: I’m reading mostly binary with some regular text interspersed, so ``Scanf`` isn’t needed most of the time.

Comment: You could try reading the text into a buffer then use `sscanf`. In my experience `sscanf` is easier to use and more dependable than scanning from a channel. I haven't used scanf in production code in decades. If your text is simple you could also just use `int_of_string` and the like. FWIW.